# Firebase-Authentication error in objects 'mAuth' and 'mCallbacks'

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

the mAuth and mCallbacks object is giving red-font-error. How to resolve this?

Do I need to make the object outside of the codeblock?

here is the code block in which the red-font errors are showing up:

```
PhoneAuthOptions options = 
  PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth) 
      .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
      .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
      .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
      .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
      .build();
  PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep following the documentation on implementing [phone authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) on Android, you'll see that the `mCallbacks` object is defined in the next step, right under the code you have above. It is explained as:

> When you call `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber`, you must also provide an instance of`OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks`, which contains implementations of the callback functions that handle the results of the request.

Under that explanation is a code sample, and then an explanation of each individual callback and its purpose.

I recommend reading the entire page first, so that you understand the complete flow, and only then starting to copy/paste the relevant code snippets.